# Inheriting an Abstract Template Class in C++ while specifying the type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Say I have a template, abstract class:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {
public:
    virtual bool foo(const T a, const T b) = 0;
}
```

And another class that wants to inherit, while getting rid of the template:

```
class MyInheritor : public MyClass<int *> {
public:
    bool foo(const int* a, const int* b) { /* stuff */ }
}
```

The above doesn't let me instantiate MyInheritor, saying it's an abstract class. How can I override the pure virtual method?

Comment: I messed up my copying, the public belonged inside of the class. My bad, edited

Answer (score 4):

Because you are not overriding anything here: the const is applied to the int and not to the pointer to int.

Here is the fixed version you probably want:

```
class MyInheritorFixed : public MyClass<int *> {
    bool foo(int* const a, int* const b) override { return true; }
};
```

[Live](http://ideone.com/98mcvy)

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to brush up on why this is the solution, not quite clear to me yet

Comment: @Chum-Chum Scarecrows  `T` is `int*`, or "pointer to `int`".  A "`const` pointer to `int*`" is written as `int* const`.  `const int*` on the otherhand is a different type: "pointer to `const int`".  Normally `const` can be used either before or after a type, e.g. `const T` or `T const`.  However, when pointers are involved, the syntax becomes more important because `const T*` and `T* const` have different meanings.